# How do I paginate my custom query?

Tags: wordpress

I have a custom query like this

```
posts_per_page=5&category_name=space
```

and I am getting the results just fine...
But i want to paginate the result, So clicking the "next 5" will show other old 5 posts...

How can I do this?

Help me please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two parts to this. First, you need to let the query know that it's paged:

```
<?php
    // This sets the page to 1 if the $paged global is empty
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

    $wp_query = new WP_Query('posts_per_page=5&category_name=space&paged=' . $paged);
?>
```

Then you need to add pagination links at the bottom of the current page's template:

```
<?php if ($wp_query->max_num_pages > 1): ?>
    <div id="nav-below" class="navigation">
        <div class="nav-previous"><?php next_posts_link('&larr; Older posts'); ?></div>
        <div class="nav-next"><?php previous_posts_link('Newer posts &rarr;'); ?></div>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. and i am getting "Older Posts" Link.. but when i click the link.. i hit the 404 page.... and there are 10 posts under space category.. can you help me

Comment: What does the url look like on the 404 page? Have you modified your `.htaccess` file?

Comment: Also, I should add here that I used an instance of the WP_Query class to perform the query. It's possible that you may want to just use the `query_posts()` function instead. In that case, you won't need the `$wp_query->` part at the top of the pagination excerpt.

Comment: no... i didnt.. its look like.. ?cat=4&paged=3, but when i modify "Blog pages show at most" to 5 then it works without problem... can u say why this is happening....

Comment: So things work well when you have a post limit of 5, but they don't work when you have more than that? Sorry if I'm not understanding you. Also: are you using `query_posts()` or a `WP_Query()` instance as I have above? Intermixing these may cause issues -- like the Next link showing up when it shouldn't, for example.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3751/discussion-between-gavin-anderegg-and-srisar)