# Add "View 20 | 50 | 100" buttons to load more Wordpress posts

Tags: wordpress

I have archive and search pages that need to have buttons that essentially change the "post_per_page" parameter. I was able to get something similar for changing the results order (name or date) like so:

`<span class="left">Sort by: <a href="' . get_bloginfo('url') . '?s=' . get_search_query() . '&orderby=title&order=asc">Name<a>;`

I tried using "&posts_per_page=20" to the link, however that does not seem to work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Review: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7539289/how-do-i-paginate-my-custom-query

Comment: Pagination works fine. I have 10 posts that load by default. I have buttons for 20, 40, 60. Clicking on the 20 button should now load 20 posts on that page.